# Session is null when redirect from one controller to another ASP.NET MVC

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-2, redirect

Why Session is null when redirection from one controller to another? And when I refresh the page again I find that the session object is not null and have data!

First controller:

```
HttpContext.Session["SiteCheckpoint"] = siteCheckpoint;
//redirect to second page controller
Response.Redirect(siteCheckpoint.FirstPageUrl + "?rf =" + referenceId);
```

Second controller:

```
if (HttpContext.Session[Resources.SessionParameter.SiteCheckpoint] != null)
{
    GetCheckpointData();
}
else 
{                
    //Raise error page
}
```

I tried this solution but it didn't work:

```
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my issue since i wasn't define any model in my view i can't pass any data to the second controller

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BCV4.Web.Redirection.Models.HomeModel>" %>
```